# max number of consecutive actions that the user performed within 30 minutes of the same day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with user,action and time.I was trying get user total action in day and max number of consecutive actions that the user performed within 30 minutes of the same day.I am new to sql ,I found total action by user but how to find max consecutive actions within 30 min .I tried below query

I SELECT  e.user, COUNT(e.user) AS count
FROM audit_log e
GROUP BY e.user

```
SELECT  e.user, COUNT(e.user) AS count
FROM audit_log e
GROUP BY e.user
```

For example lets assume that user 'userA' performed actions during the following timestamps:

```
     time        action            user
* 08:05:10       edit                A
* 08:05:40       create              B
* 08:06:50       insert              A
* 08:30:20       ...                 .
* 08:31:50
* 08:35:10
* 10:00:50
* 12:34:32       call                A
* 12:43:23       delete              A
* 12:44:00       listen              A
* 12:45:52
* 12:45:59
* 12:46:59
* 13:04:33
* 16:30:21
* 18:04:47
* 18:05:02
* 20:20:20
* 23:39:21
```

There will be an entry for this day that is like the following:

```
| username | total action count | number of consecutive actions |
|  userA   |                 19 |                             6 |
```

here is sql data

```
CREATE TABLE `audit_log` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `action_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `change_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `audit_log`
--

INSERT INTO `audit_log` (`id`, `action_name`, `user`, `change_time`) VALUES
(1, 'deploy', 'Cristina Fitzgerald', '2018-05-15 06:38:00'),
(2, 'delete', 'Kobie Tillman', '2018-05-15 06:53:00'),
(3, 'modify', 'Willa Sharpe', '2018-05-15 07:08:00'),
(4, 'delete', 'Aimee Walter', '2018-05-15 07:14:00'),
(5, 'delete', 'Willa Sharpe', '2018-05-15 07:28:00'),
(6, 'modify', 'Cristina Fitzgerald', '2018-05-15 07:38:00'),
(7, 'deploy', 'Willa Sharpe', '2018-05-15 08:28:00'),
(8, 'modify', 'Aimee Walter', '2018-05-15 09:14:00'),
(9, 'deploy', 'Kobie Tillman', '2018-05-15 09:53:00'),
(10, 'delete', 'Aimee Walter', '2018-05-15 10:09:00'),
(11, 'modify', 'Aimee Walter', '2018-05-15 10:29:00'),
(12, 'modify', 'Cristina Fitzgerald', '2018-05-15 10:38:00'),
(13, 'delete', 'Cristina Fitzgerald', '2018-05-15 11:06:00'),
(14, 'create', 'Aimee Walter', '2018-05-15 11:23:00'),
(15, 'create', 'Cristina Fitzgerald', '2018-05-15 11:44:00'),
(16, 'deploy', 'Aimee Walter', '2018-05-15 11:45:00'),
(17, 'create', 'Aimee Walter', '2018-05-15 11:58:00'),
(18, 'delete', 'Cristina Fitzgerald', '2018-05-15 12:19:00'),
(19, 'delete', 'Cristina Fitzgerald', '2018-05-15 12:23:00'),
(20, 'modify', 'Aimee Walter', '2018-05-15 12:31:00'),
(21, 'delete', 'Cristina Fitzgerald', '2018-05-15 13:14:00'),
(22, 'deploy', 'Aimee Walter', '2018-05-15 13:21:00'),
(23, 'create', 'Aimee Walter', '2018-05-15 13:24:00'),
(24, 'deploy', 'Willa Sharpe', '2018-05-15 13:28:00'),
(25, 'modify', 'Kobie Tillman', '2018-05-15 13:53:00'),
(26, 'delete', 'Kobie Tillman', '2018-05-15 14:23:00'),
(27, 'delete', 'Kobie Tillman', '2018-05-15 14:30:00'),
(28, 'create', 'Kobie Tillman', '2018-05-15 14:39:00'),
(29, 'deploy', 'Kobie Tillman', '2018-05-15 15:13:00'),
(30, 'modify', 'Willa Sharpe', '2018-05-15 15:17:00'),
(31, 'modify', 'Willa Sharpe', '2018-05-15 15:27:00'),
(32, 'create', 'Kobie Tillman', '2018-05-15 15:32:00'),
(33, 'modify', 'Kobie Tillman', '2018-05-15 15:53:00'),
(34, 'deploy', 'Kobie Tillman', '2018-05-15 16:00:00'),
(35, 'delete', 'Kobie Tillman', '2018-05-15 16:59:00'),
(36, 'deploy', 'Kobie Tillman', '2018-05-15 18:59:00'),
(37, 'modify', 'Aimee Walter', '2018-05-15 19:24:00'),
(38, 'delete', 'Willa Sharpe', '2018-05-15 19:27:00'),
(39, 'modify', 'Kobie Tillman', '2018-05-15 19:34:00'),
(40, 'delete', 'Aimee Walter', '2018-05-15 20:02:00'),
(41, 'delete', 'Willa Sharpe', '2018-05-15 20:09:00'),
(42, 'deploy', 'Aimee Walter', '2018-05-15 20:18:00'),
(43, 'delete', 'Willa Sharpe', '2018-05-15 20:40:00'),
(44, 'modify', 'Willa Sharpe', '2018-05-15 20:59:00'),
(45, 'create', 'Cristina Fitzgerald', '2018-05-15 21:14:00'),
(46, 'deploy', 'Kobie Tillman', '2018-05-15 21:34:00'),
(47, 'modify', 'Kobie Tillman', '2018-05-15 21:40:00'),
(48, 'create', 'Willa Sharpe', '2018-05-15 21:59:00'),
(49, 'delete', 'Willa Sharpe', '2018-05-15 22:51:00'),
(50, 'create', 'Willa Sharpe', '2018-05-15 23:12:00');
```

Comment: Please share create table statement and sample data as insert statements.

Comment: please check updated sql

Comment: Good one, will look at this within 20 minutes.:)

Comment: check my answer, if works we can work on performance too.

Comment: working absolutely fine.thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated One**:

- This new query reduces the number of joins,
- uses a new way to do range counting and simple joins to do the calculation.
- Indexing on `user` and `change_time` fields can be used here to make it faster.

Note: To pick records of particular time use `WHERE` condition on both tables on `change_time` fields.

```
SELECT 
    `user`,
    COUNT(0) as Total_Count,
    MAX(range_count) Max_Range_Count
FROM (
    SELECT
        a.`user`, 
        a.change_time, 
        COUNT(0) range_count
    FROM audit_log a
    INNER JOIN audit_log b ON a.`user` = b.`user` 
    WHERE b.change_time BETWEEN a.change_time AND a.change_time + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
    GROUP BY a.`user`, a.change_time
) AS user_range_count
GROUP BY `user`;
```

**Old Query**:

For now, if we don't consider performance as a factor. Here is the query to give you the desired result.

- First, create all 30 minutes ranges which can have max consecutive actions by a user.
- Second, get count per user and per 30-minute range.
- Third, get total count from table directly and get max(30-minute) range count from the previous step.

```
SELECT audit_log.user, COUNT(DISTINCT id), MAX(b.time_range_count)
FROM audit_log 
INNER JOIN (    
    SELECT audit_log.user, a.time_range, COUNT(0) as time_range_count
    FROM audit_log
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            CONCAT_WS(' - ',change_time, change_time + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) AS time_range, 
            change_time, 
            change_time + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE change_time_30
        FROM audit_log
        ORDER BY change_time
    ) AS a ON audit_log.change_time BETWEEN a.change_time AND a.change_time_30
    GROUP BY audit_log.user, a.time_range
) AS b ON audit_log.user = b.user
GROUP BY audit_log.user;
```

Comment: thanks.i cant vote for this because of less repu but i accepted this answer

Comment: if I do this with php or use your query, which will be better nd efficient way to solve this and fast. Because I think any sql query we will try will take time if records are more than 100000

Comment: If records are more and you are doing this with php, think how much data would be transferred from database to PHP, which will also be counted in performance. And Keeping that much data into RAM will also be a point during PHP processing. I would still suggest to go with MySQL.

Comment: Accepted sorry internet issue.

Comment: I am not good in mysql. So can you help me how to learn these type query because I did nt  think nested inner join will work here.

Comment: Whenever you have any issue, try it first(best way to learn), if not happy to help :)

Comment: Can check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57776762/calculates-the-amount-of-collectible-cards-which-had-to-be-bought-to-complet

Comment: I have completed this but is it tought to understand.

Comment: It's `ON HOLD` so can't provide answer but definitely will try to help.

Comment: I can show you wat I have completed. They put on hold because they could not understand this.

Comment: @savtrisharma, see my updated answer. Its better one.

Comment: Thanks., I will send you in morning

Comment: please give me your email id

Comment: ,how to do this same in php