# How to run sql custom query in incinga2?

Tags: php, icinga2

I am new to incinga2 framework,how to run sql raw or custom query in incinga2 like below

```
SELECT 
   `user`,
   COUNT(0) as Total_Count,
   MAX(range_count) Max_Range_Count
FROM (
   SELECT
       a.`user`, 
       a.change_time, 
       COUNT(0) range_count
   FROM audit_log a
   INNER JOIN audit_log b ON a.`user` = b.`user` 
   WHERE b.change_time BETWEEN a.change_time AND a.change_time + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
   GROUP BY a.`user`, a.change_time
) AS user_range_count
GROUP BY `user`
```

This database object in icinga2 for connecting database and fetch data.
They use adapter but pdo is empty. Can A add here my pdo? Is it right with icniga2 framework?

```
ipl\Sql\Connection Object
(
    [config:protected] => ipl\Sql\Config Object
        (
            [db] => mysql
            [host] => localhost
            [port] => 3306
            [dbname] => auditlog
            [username] => root
            [password] => 
            [charset] => utf8
            [options] => 
            [type] => db
            [persistent] => 0
        )

    [pdo:protected] => 
    [queryBuilder:protected] => 
    [adapter:protected] => ipl\Sql\Adapter\Mysql Object
        (
            [quoteCharacter:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => `
                    [1] => `
                )

            [escapeCharatcer:protected] => ``
            [escapeCharacter:protected] => \"
            [options:protected] => Array
                (
                    [8] => 0
                    [20] => 
                    [3] => 2
                    [11] => 0
                    [17] => 
                )

        )

    [pluginLoaders:protected] => Array
        (
            [adapter] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ipl\Stdlib\Loader\AutoLoadingPluginLoader Object
                        (
                            [namespace:protected] => ipl\Sql\Adapter
                            [postfix:protected] => 
                            [uppercaseFirst:protected] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: You can't because icinga2 doesn't provide a mysql interface. You would rather do this using the mysql shell, phpmyadmin or php libraries like pdo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php).

Very Nice article to get started with PDO.

1. [How to connect to MySQL using PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql)
2. [Select query with PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/select)

```
$strQuery = "SELECT 
   `user`,
   COUNT(0) as Total_Count,
   MAX(range_count) Max_Range_Count
FROM (
   SELECT
       a.`user`, 
       a.change_time, 
       COUNT(0) range_count
   FROM audit_log a
   INNER JOIN audit_log b ON a.`user` = b.`user` 
   WHERE b.change_time BETWEEN a.change_time AND a.change_time + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
   GROUP BY a.`user`, a.change_time
) AS user_range_count
GROUP BY `user`";

foreach ($conn->query($strQuery) as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: i cant  run this  in incing2 i have to do this with php [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57825536/max-number-of-consecutive-actions-that-the-user-performed-within-30-minutes-of-t]

Comment: PDO stands for PHP Data Objects. So this code is PHP only. Use this in PHP. See the first reference and see how to connect to mysql, after that this code will return you the required output.

Comment: i have updated my question,this is icinga2 is use for datatbase

Comment: Will check on that.

Comment: icinga2  seems to be like MySQL monitoring system, not the actual wrapper for data fetching. Still I saw some examples that allows you to run some queries but mostly all are of status check. I don't know about Incinga but still let me know? Are you able to run a simple query like `select * from some_table`?

Comment: [How to monitor your MySQL Server](https://icinga.com/2017/06/12/how-to-monitor-your-mysql-servers-with-icinga-2/)

Comment: @savtrisharma, did you check on this?

Comment: no sorry did not check before that i checked its documentation of ipl module so there was function to fetch data from sql

Answer (score 0):

First Install any database resource module in incinga
like **Icinga Web 2 - IPL**
it will help us to call pdo queries in incinga
then you can check its documentation how to run any statement with binding parameter.
example:

```
use ipl\Sql\Select;
use PDO;
$stmt = 'Select * from table where id=?';
$id=1;
$execute=$this->dbConnection->fetchAll($stmt,[$id]);
```